# A little help required on sending email notifications something similar to Job alerts

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a email notifications system which are sent when a new item is added into the database.

Users register by providing their email address and by selecting their preferences which are as below -

```
Color [n/a, pink, red, blue, and green]
Shape [n/a, square, rectangle, and circle]
width [n/a, narrow, wide]
```

These all are dropdown lists.

So if a user selects Color as red and leaves all other options as n/a, then it would mean they wanted to receive notifications for any new item which has color as red. If they select Colore = red and Shape = circle, they want to receive notifications for only those items which have color red AND shape as circle.

Item table

```
id, color, shape, width, height, name, description, image
```

sample rows

```
1, red, circle, narrow, tall, ABC, ABC Descrip, yellowFlag.jpg
2, blue, circle, wide, short, XYZ, XYZ Descrip, redFlag.jpg
```

Notifications table

```
id, email, color, shape, width
```

sample rows

```
1, test@dummy.org.uk, red, 0, 0, 0
2, xyz@alpha.com, blue, circle, 0
3, abc@abcdef.com, pink, square, wide
```

A use can opt for any of the selections. For example, see below, they can select

```
color = red, shape = 0, width = 0 [0 is n/a, selected red only]
color = 0, shape = square, width= 0 [selected shape only]
color = 0, shape = 0, width= 'narrow' [selected width only]
color = red, shape = square, width= 0 [selected both color and shape but not width]
color = 0, shape = square, width= 'narrow' [selected both shape and width but not color]
color = red, shape = square, width= narrow [selected all 3 options]
color = red, shape = 0, width= narrow [selected color and width but not shape]
```

My questions are -
If I add number 2 item (above in item table) into DB, I want to send notifications to the users who have a match in notifications table. The only way to query notifications table I can think of is something like

```
1. SELECT email FROM notifications WHERE color = 'blue', shape = '0', '0'
2. SELECT email FROM notifications WHERE color = 'blue', shape = 'circle', '0'
3. SELECT email FROM notifications WHERE color = 'blue', shape = 'circle', 'wide'
4. SELECT email FROM notifications WHERE color = '0', shape = '0', 'wide'
5. SELECT email FROM notifications WHERE color = 'blue', shape = 'circle', '0'
6. SELECT email FROM notifications WHERE color = 'blue', shape = 'circle', 'wide'
```

... and so on

It is an inefficient method. Also as of now number of options is 3 (color, shape, width) but If  have to add another couple of options it will all go mad (alongwith me).  There must a better way to achieve this as there are lots of application already doing it like job alerts etc. Could you suggest me a better alternative/idea to manage these. I have not got any problem changing structure of tables etc so any ideas are welcome. If you have any questions please ask. I appreciate your help.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a table that gathers all the preferences for a given user:

Table criteria:

```
id: some ID for the criteria
label: human readable description of the criteria
column: name of the corresponding column in the notification table
values: optional comma-separated list of possible values
```

Table user_preferences

```
id: some id for the preference
user_id: the user
criteria_id: the criteria
value: the chosen value for the criteria
```

Now to find the users with blue color and square shape preferences:

```
SELECT u.id, u.email 
FROM user u, criteria c, user_preferences up
WHERE
      up.id = u.id
  AND c.id = up.criteria_id
  AND c.column = 'shape' 
  AND up.value='square'

INTERSECT

SELECT u.id, u.email 
FROM user u, criteria c, user_preferences up
WHERE
      up.id = u.id
  AND c.id = up.criteria_id
  AND c.column = 'color' 
  AND up.value='blue'
```

And when you add an item, you'll want to find users with blue color **or** square shape preferences:

```
SELECT u.id, u.email 
FROM user u, criteria c, user_preferences up
WHERE
      up.id = u.id
  AND c.id = up.criteria_id
  AND ( (c.column = 'shape' AND up.value='square')
     OR (c.column = 'color' AND up.value='blue')
  )
```

Comment: Did you mean to have a pre-built list of criteria and then allow the user to choose one?

Comment: I read once again your question, just replace user by notification to stick to the terms of the question. And yes, have a list of criterias (with possibly restricted values), allow the user to choose one or more of them. Note that nothing has been tested, but it should give a solid/expandable base to your notification system

Comment: Also, the criterias could be re-used by the item table, this way you might even be able to further automate the process of notification (make it independant of whatever the item lists as property)

Comment: Actually Color, shape, width are db tables and I am using their ids in item and notification tables. I just used values, such as red, square, to a bit more clear in the question above. So an admin can add more colors or more shapes and these get available for the notification. I am just thinking how to use your answer and make it fit to my requirement. Big thanks for replying :)

Comment: Then simply consider that the possible values for the user_preference->value fields are the IDs of the color/shape/... You'd need to add a "foreign_table" field to the criteria table in order to be able to fetch the required information in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

That means if you insert a row in item table, values color=red,shape=0,width=0.............

then you select the email id of particular matching values color=red,shape=0,width=0 from 
Notifications table.

am i correct???????

Go to your process page. that is insert query page. then select the data from there by using this post data.

for example

```
$color=$_POST['color'];
$shape=$_POST['shape'];
$width=$_POST['width'];
```

then use the select query

```
"select email from notifications where color='$color' and shape='$shape' and width='$width'"
```

i hope this is your needs......

but thats not a problem 
in notification table also you use the value 0.

if a user choose red only, your insertion query enter color=red and shape,width as 0.
so that will ensure your needs

Comment: Yes something like that. When a new item is added into database, then I need to check if there are any users whose request match the values in ITEMs table.

Comment: if a user has selected color = red, then this means they want to receive notifications for any item which has color red regardless of the shape and width. Above will not help in this case. :(